# How do I dynamically build an ng-include src?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

I have the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="module in modules" id="{{module.Id}}">
    <ng-include ng-init="bootstrapModule(module.Id)" src=""></ng-include>
</div>
```

I want to be able to build a string in src like so:

```
/modules/{{module.Name}}/{{module.Name}}.tpl.html
```

But I keep hitting roadblocks. I've tried to use a call back function to build it,

```
$scope.constructTemplateUrl = function(id) {
    return '/modules/' + id + '/' + id + '.tpl.html';
}
```

But this gets called over & over & over and it doesn't seem to like that. I've also tried to construct it like so:

```
ng-src="/modules/{{module.Id}}/{{module.Id}}.tpl.html"
```

But that isn't working either. Rather than spend hours beating around the bush, I wondered if anyone else has come up against something like this and has any ideas?

Also, when I grab the modules from $resource, I am returning them asynchronously with $q, so I can't seem to go through and add it into the modules before in the controller as `$scope.modules` just equals a `then` function at that point.

Any ideas?

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`ngInclude | src` directive requires an angular expression, which means you should probably write

`ng-src="'/modules/' + module.Id + '/tpl.html'"`

From http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude

> ngInclude|src string   angular expression evaluating to URL. If the
>   source is a string constant, make sure you wrap it in quotes, e.g.
>   src="'myPartialTemplate.html'".

It might be better if you construct the url in model instead of inline HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="module in modules" id="{{module.Id}}">
    <ng-include src="module.url"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Comment: Your method works now, but I was sure I tried it before, I must have been using ng-src instead of just src. Thanks @rogerz!

Comment: @rogerz - This works for me too.  In my example it works but I get a 404 error in the console. See answer to:http://stackoverflow.com/a/33299027/828282
Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: `<div ng-repeat="module in modules" id="{{module.Id}}" ng-include src="module.url"></div>`